# Putting a HashMap inside a HashMap then populating the two maps.

Tags: java, hashmap

I have to write a script for sql inserts.  I have all the information that I need in order to write the inserts but there are three different pieces of information that I'm using and not just two.  I know that I have to put a Map inside a Map but I am getting a compile error when I try to put anything into the maps.

```
HashMap<String,String> acctyp = new HashMap<String,String>();
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> gens = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
gens.put("'GEN01'", acctyp.put("'Open'","ACCTYP 01"));
gens.put("'GEN02'", acctyp.put("'Sheltered'","ACCTYP 02"));
gens.put("'GEN03'", acctyp.put("'Spousal sheltered'","ACCTYP 03"));
gens.put("'GEN06'", acctyp.put("'Education'","ACCTYP 06"));
gens.put("'GEN12'", acctyp.put("'Non-ded. sheltered'","ACCTYP 12"));
gens.put("'GEN30'", acctyp.put("'Structured Product'","ACCTYP 30"));
gens.put("'GEN31'", acctyp.put("'Emergency Cash'","ACCTYP 31"));
gens.put("'GEN85'", acctyp.put("'Insurance Savings'","ACCTYP 85"));
gens.put("'GEN86'", acctyp.put("'Stock Option'","ACCTYP 86"));
gens.put("'GEN94'", acctyp.put("'Business Other'","ACCTYP 94"));
gens.put("'GEN95'", acctyp.put("'Personal use'","ACCTYP 95"));
gens.put("'GEN97'", acctyp.put("'Universal Life'","ACCTYP 97"));
```

If anyone has any insight of why I'm getting a compile error on the puts then it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the intent of the code above? Do you want all of the keys in the outer map (gens) to refer to the same object (acctype)?

Comment: A hashmap of hashmaps might not be the best datastructure for what you are doing here.  It might be simpler to create an AccountInfo class which has three strings as members.  Then you could just store a list of AccountInfo objects - if all you need is a list of values to pass into a SQL insert.

Comment: I agree with @GrahamGriffiths that HashMap is not the type for the job.  I reccomend guava's HashBasedTable: `Table<String, String, String> gens = HashBasedTable.create(); gens.put("'GEN01","Open", "ACCTYP 01");`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Map.put` returns a string. gens is mapping `String` to `HashMap`.  You are calling `gens.put(string, string)` and should instead be calling `gens.put(string, HashMap<string,string>)`

Your code should read:

```
HashMap<String,String> acctyp = new HashMap<String,String>();
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> gens = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
acctyp.put("'Open'","ACCTYP 01");
gens.put("'GEN01'", acctyp);
```

Comment: No problem, if you have any other questions let me know. Please accept to close the question if not, @ChrisQuibell

Answer (score 3):

Your code should like this

```
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> gens = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> acctyp =  new HashMap<String,String>();
        acctyp.put("'Open'","ACCTYP 01");
        gens.put("'GEN01'", acctyp);
        acctyp =  new HashMap<String,String>();
        acctyp.put("'Sheltered'","ACCTYP 02");
        gens.put("'GEN02'", acctyp);
        acctyp =  new HashMap<String,String>();
        acctyp.put("'Spousal sheltered'","ACCTYP 03");
        gens.put("'GEN03'",acctyp );
        acctyp =  new HashMap<String,String>();
        acctyp.put("'Education'","ACCTYP 06");
        gens.put("'GEN06'",acctyp );            
        acctyp =  new HashMap<String,String>();
        acctyp.put("'Non-ded. sheltered'","ACCTYP 12");
        gens.put("'GEN06'",acctyp );
        acctyp =  new HashMap<String,String>();
        acctyp.put("'Structured Product'","ACCTYP 30");
        gens.put("'GEN06'",acctyp );

        acctyp =  new HashMap<String,String>();
        acctyp.put("'Emergency Cash'","ACCTYP 31");
        gens.put("'GEN06'",acctyp );
```

Answer (score 2):

Because [Map#put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)) returns a String value. When you do this : `acctyp.put("'Open'","ACCTYP 01")` , it actually returns a `String` hence `gens.put("'GEN01'", acctyp.put("'Open'","ACCTYP 01"));` is a compilation error.

What I suppose you want is :

```
HashMap<String,String> acctyp = new HashMap<String,String>();
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> gens = new 
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
acctyp.put("'Open'","ACCTYP 01");
acctyp.put("'Sheltered'","ACCTYP 02");
acctyp.put("'Spousal sheltered'","ACCTYP 03");
gens.put("'GEN01'", acctype);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also write this code if you want to fill the second hashmap later on:

```
acctype.put("'Open'",new Hashmap<String,String>()); 
acctype.put("''Sheltered'",new Hashmap<String,String>());
... So on
actttype.get("'Open'").put("'Sheltered'","ACCTYP 02")
acttype.get("'Sheltered'").put("'Spousal sheltered'","ACCTYP 03")
and so on ...
```

hope that helps too

Answer (score 0):

static Map < String, Map < String, Integer >> divisons = new HashMap < String, Map < String, Integer >> ();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map < String, Integer > studentMarksA = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
    Map < String, Integer > studentMarksB = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
    Map < String, Integer > studentMarksC = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
    // Entering for marks for divison A
    divisons.put("9A", studentMarksA);
    studentMarksA.put("Agniv", 60);
    studentMarksA.put("Bhuvan", 70);
    studentMarksA.put("Chandan", 80);
    // Entering for marks for divison B
    divisons.put("9B", studentMarksB);
    studentMarksB.put("Dev", 50);
    studentMarksB.put("Ejazd", 90);
    studentMarksB.put("Faruk", 61);
    // Entering for marks for divison C
    divisons.put("9C", studentMarksC);
    studentMarksC.put("Govind", 68);
    studentMarksC.put("Harish", 71);
    studentMarksC.put("Ishwar", 84);

    getRecord("B");
}
```

Comment: I have implemented HashMap of HashMap like this its working for me.. Kindly let me know if it works for you..

Comment: The below is my main hashmap for the above code :

Suppose there are classes 9A,9B, 9C and there are 3 Students who has % of marks as Agniv from 9A has 70% .

static Map < String, Map < String, Integer >> divisons = new HashMap < String, Map < String, Integer >> ();

Comment: Please don't use the comments to make updates. You can edit your answer instead. That way you can format code to look nice.

Answer (score -1):

```
 - I think u should do like this way..

   HashMap<String,String> acctyp = new HashMap<String,String>();
   HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> gens = new
   HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();

    acctyp.put("'Open'","ACCTYP 01");
           gens.put("'GEN01'", acctyp);
           acctyp.put("'Sheltered'","ACCTYP 02");
           gens.put("'GEN02'", acctyp);
           acctyp.put("'Spousal sheltered'","ACCTYP 03");
           gens.put("'GEN03'",acctyp );
```